# Why "assert_response" ignores the custom message in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, functional-testing

In my functional test I verify the response status like that:

```
assert_response :error, "My error message"
```

However, Rails ignores my custom message and reports:

> Expected response to be a <:error>, but was <201>

Any ideas why?

I use Rails 3.2.6.

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering the same thing. Turns out it's been fixed on Github: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d28a15ede59f6434f1b7a8d01be060fa73b4746c

For me, updating rails/the actionpack gem to the latest version hadn't included that fix, but I was able to update response.rb manually. It was located at:

```
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/response.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

In your test you have mentioned the response type as :error which matches to status code 500-599. But as your test is returning status code 201 it is not able to match that and showing the message according to the definition of assert_response which is

```
def assert_response(type, message = nil)
    clean_backtrace do
      if [ :success, :missing, :redirect, :error ].include?(type) && @response.send("#{type}?")
        assert_block("") { true } # to count the assertion
      elsif type.is_a?(Fixnum) && @response.response_code == type
        assert_block("") { true } # to count the assertion
      else
        assert_block(build_message(message, "Expected response to be a <?>, but was <?>", type, @response.response_code)) { false }
      end               
    end
end
```

it goes into else due to the type and status code mismatch and gives that message.

Here are the type of response and their matching codes:

```
:success: Status code was 200
:redirect: Status code was in the 300-399 range
:missing: Status code was 404
:error: Status code was in the 500-599 range
```

Comment: @Misha did it helped? or it has any issue

Comment: Note there are many more statuses that can be asserted. Here's a complete list:  https://github.com/chneukirchen/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/utils.rb#L478